# Embedded Jetty: how to run security handler as soon as http requests arrive?

Tags: jersey, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am using embedded Jetty along with Jersey. My question is: is it possible to make the `SecurityHandler` of jetty take effect before the HTTP request reaching the Jersey class?

Here is my code: (I am sorry it may be too much.)
The class where the jetty server initialized:

```java
public class JettyHttpComponent extends AbstractLifeCycleComponent {

    private static final String REST_SOURCE_KEY = "jersey.config.server.provider.classnames";

    //TODO Security config and implementation
    public int start() throws RuntimeException {

        Server jettyServer = new Server(8080);
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(jettyServer, "/", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS|ServletContextHandler.SECURITY);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        context.setSecurityHandler(basicAuth());


        ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(
             org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*");
        jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

        //load rest resources
        jerseyServlet.setInitParameter(REST_SOURCE_KEY, IndexService.class.getCanonicalName());


        try {
            jettyServer.start();
            jettyServer.join();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            jettyServer.destroy();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public int stop() throws RuntimeException {
        //close resources
        try {
            close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Server stopped.");
        return 0;
    }

    private SecurityHandler basicAuth() {
        ConstraintSecurityHandler securityHandler = new ConstraintSecurityHandler();
        LoginService loginService = new LDAPLoginService();
        securityHandler.setLoginService(loginService);  
        return securityHandler;
    }

}
```

The `LDAPLoginService` class in `basicAuth()` is my customized login class extending `AbstractLoginService`.

The Jersey class handling http request:

```java
@Path("/index")
public class IndexService extends BaseRestService {

    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response index(@Context SecurityContext securityContext,
            @Context HttpHeaders headers,
            @Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
            @QueryParam("algorithm") String algorithm,
            @QueryParam("executionMode") String mode,
            String request) {
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String response = null;
        IndexContext context = null;
        try {
            init();
            //setup context with security, headers, options and request
            ServiceUserContext suc = buildServiceUserContext(securityContext, httpRequest);
            if (suc == null) {
                return Response.status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity(response).build();
            }
            ServiceDataContext sdc = buildServiceDataContext(request);
            context = IndexContext.builder().algorithm(algorithm).serviceDataContext(sdc).
                    serviceUserContext(suc).build();
            //dispatch service to entity matching core services
            dispatch(context);
        } catch(Throwable t) {
            handlerErrors(t, context);
        } finally {
            if (context != null) {
                close(context);
                response = context.getServiceDataContext().getResponse();
                System.out.println("Index takes: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t1) + " ms");
            }
        }
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(response).build();
    }   
}
```

In the method `buildServiceDataContext()`, I called `securityContext.getUserPrincipal()`, and the `LDAPLoginService` class  extending `AbstractLoginService` does nothing until `securityContext.getUserPrincipal()` is reached. Is it possible to run the security check at the very beginning, even before Jersey class begins to handle the request? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @Paul Samsotha suggested, `ContainerRequestFilter` is a good choice.